# Update query to change filed from one table which is depend on other

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

i have two tables owner and member, in member table there is field mid ,same name field mid in owner but with null values ,i want update mid from owner table as the value inserted in mid of member table, both mid should be same. using hibernate so I tried it but query is not correct.

```
public void updateOwnerMember(Owner owner) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    String hql="update Owner set Owner.mId = Member.mId from Member Owner inner join mId Member on Member.mId = Owner.mID where Owner.mId is null ";
    Query query=sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setInteger(0,1);
    query.setInteger(1,2);
    query.executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if mId is not the primary key, otherwise you have nothing to join them on.

Example query (not validated):

```
UPDATE Owner 
SET Owner.mId = (SELECT Member.mId FROM Member WHERE m.id = o.id)
```

Comment: how can i join mId from member table to owner table?

Comment: Member.mId = Owner.mId, but you can not join these if they contain nulls. If one value is null, mysql wont know how to connect the 2 items